# Get sorted items by count ids from other database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have main table with heroes, [id, name], and i have second table with skills of all heroes [hero_id, skill_id (unique for every hero), name (name of skill)].

I want get all data from main table which be sorted by skills numbers.

Example:

main

```
[0, Rickimary]
[1, Axega],
[2, Morti]
```

second

```
[0, 0, Invisibie]
[0, 1, Smoke],
[0, 2, Jump],
[1, 0, Big hit],
[2, 0, Slice],
[2, 1, Froze]
```

And take results as

```
[0, Rickimary],
[2, Marti],
[1, Axage]
```

or descending

Comment: @Dharman Okay, in the future I will only indicate the correct tags

Comment: Completely different databases, or different tables in the same database, which would make a lot more sense?

Comment: @Shawn yeah, my bad, i edited it

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` and `group by`:

```
select m.name, count(s.skill_id)
from main m left join
     second s
     on m.id = s.hero_id
group by m.id, m.name
order by count(s.skill_id) desc;
```